# How to compare two independent samples using a permutation test?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, permutation-test

Suppose I have two independent samples. How can I test if the two samples have been drawn from the same distribution using a permutation test? The sample sizes are equal. The population distributions are unknown.

Comment: You need to start with what kinds of differences you want most to pick up. If you're just after *any* kind of difference in distribution, the usual two sample test statistics (such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov, for example) might be a suitable statistic for a permutation test..

Comment: I wrote my answer to the duplicate specifically to address future related questions like this one.